# Extract a word from regular expression using python data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, regex, dataframe

This is the data I'm working with:

```
Topic                                 About                                                     Group Discussion
microwave is not working              i tried turning on the microwave and it wont turn on      [[person1 yeah the microwave wont turn on i tested it], [person2 okay send it over to warranty], ...]
the light of the oven wont turn on    i have tried to press the light on the oven and nothing   [[person3 did you power on the oven], [person4 it was powered on], ...]
water will not come out of sink       i turn the valve and nothing comes out of the sink        [[person5 okay it looks like water is not coming out of the sink], [person6 okay send it over to this department to take a look], ...]
```

What I would like is this:

```
Topic                                 About                                                     Group Discussion                                                                                                                           Topic_Extract         About_Extract        Group_Discussion_Extract
microwave is not working              i tried turning on the microwave and it wont turn on      [[person1 yeah the microwave wont turn on i tested it], [person2 okay send it over to warranty], ...]                                      microwave             microwave            microwave
the light of the oven wont turn on    i have tried to press the light on the oven and nothing   [[person3 did you power on the oven], [person4 it was powered on], ...]                                                                    oven                  oven                 oven
water will not come out of sink       i turn the valve and nothing comes out of the sink        [[person5 okay it looks like water is not coming out of the sink], [person6 okay send it over to this department to take a look], ...]     sink                  sink                 sink
```

**EDIT:**
Okay, now it's saying everything is 'unclassified' not sure how to fix this:

```
df['Title_Extract'] = ''
def loop(data):
    for i,j in data['Topic'].iteritems():
        if (re.search(r'microwave|microwave will not turn on|microwave is not working|microwave wont work|microwave will not work|microwave is broken', j) == True):
            return(data['Topic_Extract'].str.replace('', 'microwave'))
        elif (re.search(r'oven|oven will not turn on|oven is not working|oven wont work|oven will not work|oven is broken|oven wont turn on', j) == True):
            return(data['Topic_Extract'].str.replace('', 'oven'))
        elif (re.search(r'sink|sink will not turn on|sink is not working|sink wont work|sink will not work|sink is broken|sink wont turn on', j) == True):
            return(data['Topic_Extract'].str.replace('', 'sink'))
        else:
            return 'unclassified'

loop(df)
```

I am running into the following error when I'm trying to extract a word - not classifying correctly:

```
0        unclassified
...
2        unclassified
```

Comment: I dont see the difference between the two provided data frames. Can you elaborate?

Comment: added a solution, does it help?

Comment: @ARK1375: I had the same issue. Scroll to the right.

Comment: Scroll to the right side of the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks for the help everyone. This is what my solution looks like:

```
def loop(data):
    for i,j in data['Topic'].iteritems():
        if (re.search(r'\bmicrowave\b', j)):
            data['Topic Extract'][i].append('microwave')
        elif (re.search(r'\boven\b', j)):
            data['Topic Extract'][i].append('oven')
        elif (re.search(r'\bsink\b', j)):
            data['Topic Extract'][i].append('sink')
        else:
            data['Topic Extract'][i].append('unclassified')
    return data

df = loop(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

create a list of values to search. then use findall to return the values that are found in the df column

```
topic_terms = ['microwave','sink', 'oven']
df['term']=df['Topic'].str.findall("|".join(terms))
df
```

data used

```
data = {'Topic': {0: 'microwave is not working ',
  1: 'the light of the oven wont turn on ',
  2: 'water will not come out of sink '},
 'About': {0: 'i tried turning on the microwave and it wont turn on ',
  1: 'i have tried to press the light on the oven and nothing ',
  2: 'i turn the valve and nothing comes out of the sink '},
 'Group Discussion': {0: '[[person1 yeah the microwave wont turn on i tested it], [person2 okay send it over to warranty], ...]',
  1: '[[person3 did you power on the oven], [person4 it was powered on], ...]',
  2: '[[person5 okay it looks like water is not coming out of the sink], [person6 okay send it over to this department to take a look], ...'}}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

```
Topic   About   Group Discussion    term
0   microwave is not working    i tried turning on the microwave and it wont t...   [[person1 yeah the microwave wont turn on i te...   microwave
1   the light of the oven wont turn on  i have tried to press the light on the oven an...   [[person3 did you power on the oven], [person4...   oven
2   water will not come out of sink     i turn the valve and nothing comes out of the ...   [[person5 okay it looks like water is not comi...   sink
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an empty list

Comment: Did it worked with the data frame from the solution? Or it’s empty list from your data frame.

Comment: The data frame has the new column ['Title_Extract'] but looking down the column it's just [empty] for every row

Comment: I can't tell from your description, i added screenshot of my notebook using the data you shared in the question. You need to share your implementation of this solution. There might be some typo. if you share the data as a code, I can try it

Comment: Oh, your terms in the join has to be 'topic_terms'.

Comment: Well, the thing is I would like to add lots of regular expressions. I have modified my question with my code sample I'd like to use

Comment: I changed the variable name but missed updating the findall, i updated the image